# How to get first argument of a program call

Tags: c, scanf, argv, atoi

I'm making a program in C and this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    char aux[10];
    sscanf(argv[1], "%[^-]", aux);
    n = atoi(aux);
}
```

So, if I run the program from command line: my_program -23, I want to get the number "23" to isolate it in a var like an integer, but this don't work and I don't know why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sscanf` call is trying to read anything up to (but not including) the first `-` in the string. Since the `-` is (presumably) the first character, it `aux` ends up empty.

You could do something like: `sscanf(argv[1], "%*[-]%d", &n);`. This will skip across any leading `-` characters, so arguments of `23`, `-23` and `--23` will all be treated identically. If you want `--23` to be interpreted as `-23` (only the one leading dash signals a flag), then you could use `sscanf(argv[1], "-%d", &n);` (and in this case, with just `23` on the command line, the conversion will fail outright).

Comment: Yeah, with the first form work fine, but I see more simple the second form (sscanf(argv[1], "-%d", &n);) and work fine too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

check your sscanf format, and I assume aux is an integer?

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/
sscanf (str,"%d",&n);

Comment: it's an array of char, after that I convert it with atoi to an integer